# jQuery mousewheel event - javascript equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I'm using a `mousewheel / wheel` event to zoom in/out on my page. When I call it with `el.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", functionName)` jQuery handler, it runs smoothly and everything works fine, `event.delta` has consistent values.

On the other hand, when I call the **same function** with `el.addEventListener("wheel", functionName)`, the scroll is all over the place, sometimes it triggers, sometimes it doesn't, `event.deltaY` changes the sign depending on how it feels at the moment, unrelated to the direction of my wheel.

Is there a way to achieve the smoothness of the jQuery event without loading the whole library only for that single purpose? How would I go about writing/finding the equivalent?

**Solved:** The event wasn't causing the stutter, `event.deltaY` property was. Javascript wheel property `event.wheelDeltaY` is the equivalent to jQuery's `event.delta`.

[Object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent)
Thank you @CBroe

Comment: I am guessing that is probably not due to "jQuery vs vanilla JS", but because they are different events to begin with. And https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent even says you should not rely on the `delta` values with that one (and what to do instead.)

Comment: As noted above - what if you do `el.on("wheel", functionName)`?

Comment: From what I remember, delta is handled differently in js vs jquery wheel events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event

Comment: @freedomn-m That also works fine, I don't know what could be causing it. The only thing I change is `event.delta` to `event.deltaY` to get the direction.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! Turns out there is a `event.wheelDeltaY` that completely solves the stutter! There was confusion with the documentation since I was previously using this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event